# Get data from table that is the parent of the foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `Contribution` and `Payment`. The `contribution` table holds the data like `project_id, user_id, email`. The `Payment` table holds the data like `contribution_id, state`.

Basically, if a user just fills and submit the form before payment, the data is then stored in `contribution` table. If the user completes the whole payment action after submitting the form, then it is stored in `Payment` table.

Now I want to just fetch the `email and user_id` from the `Contribution` table whose project_id = x and their contribution `Payment.state == paid`.

Any idea how I can do this in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it depends on how large your tables are, then we will have many solutions.

The simple query is

```
 SELECT email, user_id
   FROM Contribution c
   JOIN Payment p ON c.contribution_id = p.contribution_id
  WHERE p.state = 'state'
        AND c.project_id = 'x'
```

I hope that I understand your question right and this answer is satisfy you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` to achieve this as follows,

```
select email, user_id  
from Contribution a join Payment b on a.contribution_id = b.contribution_id
where a.project_id = x and b.state = 'paid';
```